# Calculating quarterly and yearly avarage through javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
const test = [1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
```

I want to group the elements of the array into chunks of size 3 (quarters) and size 12 (years):

```
const quarters = [[1,2,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18],[19,20]];
const years = [[1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]];
```

I also want to compute the sum of each chunk:

```
const quarterSums = [5,15,24,33,42,51,39];
const yearSums = [77,132];
```

How do I do so?

Comment: please add the wanted result and what you have tried.

Comment: The output should be like this:
Quarters: [5,15,24,43] : sum of each 3 elements
Years: [77,222] sum of each 12 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group elements into chunks of size `n` then:

```js
const groupInto = (n, xs) => xs.reduce((xss, x, i) => {
    if (i % n === 0) xss.push([]); // create a new group
    xss[xss.length - 1].push(x);   // push in last group
    return xss;
}, []);

const xs = [1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

const quarters = groupInto(3,  xs);
const years    = groupInto(12, xs);

console.log(JSON.stringify(quarters));
console.log(JSON.stringify(years));
```

On the other hand, if you want to find the sum of these chunks:

```js
const sumInto = (n, xs) => xs.reduce((ys, x, i) => {
    if (i % n === 0) ys.push(0);
    ys[ys.length - 1] += x;
    return ys;
}, []);

const xs = [1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

const quarters = sumInto(3,  xs);
const years    = sumInto(12, xs);

console.log(JSON.stringify(quarters));
console.log(JSON.stringify(years));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop that increments by the group size, and use `.slice()`.

*EDIT: You added information not in the original question. Since you seem to want the sum of each quarter/year, add this `.reduce((s,n)=>s+n, 0)` to each subset. This shows a better use of `.reduce()`.*

```js
const test = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

console.log(getGroups(test, 3)); // quarters
console.log(getGroups(test, 12)); // years

function getGroups(a, s) {
  for (var i = 0, r = []; i < a.length; i += s) {
    r.push(a.slice(i, i + s).reduce((s,n)=>s + n, 0));
  }
  return r;
}
```

Using something like `.reduce()` that visits every element makes it more complicated in this case. The traditional `for` loop provides the benefit of defining how the loop should be incremented.

---

If you prefer a more function way, I'd still not use `.reduce()`, but would roll my own tail recursion.

```js
const test = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

console.log(getGroups(test, 3)); // quarters
console.log(getGroups(test, 12)); // years

function getGroups(a, s) {
  return function p(a, s, r) {
    return !a.length ? r : r.concat(a.slice(0, s).reduce((s,n)=>s + n, 0),
                                    p(a.slice(s), s, r));
  }(a, s, []);
}
```

Comment: Using `reduce` doesn't make it more complicated. Stop spreading misinformation.

Comment: @AaditMShah: Using any construct that visits every element in a case where you only need to visit a subset adds complication. You need to write extra code that determines if you're at the start of a subset or in the middle.

Comment: `0` initial value in your `reduce` expression is not necessary

Comment: @UlysseBN: I always include it out of habit. You're right that in this case `size` should never be `0` (though a check should really be added for that) so it shouldn't be needed, but it's still not a bad habit to include it since JS will throw when calling `.reduce()` on an empty Array if the initializer isn't included.

Comment: @spanky I disagree. Adding one conditional doesn't make the code more complex. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45696415/783743) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with an object as temporary variable for collecting the values. Then calculate the average.

```js
var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
    temp = { quarter: { avg: [], items: 3, sum: 0 }, year: { avg: [], items: 12, sum: 0 } }
  
values.forEach(function (v, i) {
    Object.keys(temp).forEach(function (k) {
        temp[k].sum += v;
        if (i && (i + 1) % temp[k].items === 0) {
            temp[k].avg.push(temp[k].sum / temp[k].items);
            temp[k].sum = 0;
        }
    });
});

console.log(temp.quarter.avg);
console.log(temp.year.avg);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```